# How to create a function and pass a variable to it using a custom php MVC

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

Im working with a custom PHP MVC  application

I retrieved a list of posts using this method:

> **MODELs:** videos_model.php

```
class Index_Model extends Model {
    public function fetchVideos(){      
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM bv_videos");
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $stmt->fetchAll();

    }
}
```

> **CONTROLLERs :**
>   video.php
>       class Index extends Controller {

```
    public function index(){    

        $this->view->render('../../public/templates/header');       
        $this->view->Videos         = $this->model->fetchVideos();      
        $this->view->render('index/index');
        $this->view->render('../../public/templates/footer');
    }
}
```

> **Views :**

```
<div class="entry-header video_frame_description">
    <h3><?php echo $value->title; ?></h3>

    <p class="pull-left post-info">           
        <span class="cat-links hidden-xs">
            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>?cat=<?php echo $value->cat_id; ?>">
            Category: 
            ** HERE I WANT TO ADD CATEGORY NAME UNDER EACH POST **
            </a>
     </p>
</div>
```

In the view, I want to  show the name of the video category under each post.

I created this function in the index class

```
public function get_video_category($cat_id){        

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  bv_categories WHERE cat_id=?");
        $stmt->execute(array($cat_id));
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);    
        $data = $stmt->fetch();
        return $data->category;
}
```

And then in the Controller I added this line:

```
$this->view->video_category = $this->model->get_video_category();
```

And here the problem. What parameter should I pass the get_video_category() function??

Here are the tables structure im using:

**bv_videos**

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bv_videos` (
>   `video_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   `url` text NOT NULL,
>   `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `date_added` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`video_id`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

**bv_categories**

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bv_categories` (
>   `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `category` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   `order_cat` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',
>   PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extend this query

```
"SELECT * FROM bv_videos"
```

to

```
SELECT v.*, c.category as category_name FROM bv_videos v, bv_categories c WHERE v.cat_id = b.cat_id and v.cat_id = " . $cat_id;
```

or using left join

and then in view would just call category same way as you use category id

```
 <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>?cat=<?php echo $value->cat_id; ?>">
Category name is: $value->category_name;
```

Your way:

```
$this->view->video_category = $this->model->get_video_category();
```

you need to enter category id, which seems to be **$value->cat_id;** if you are calling from view

Comment: Thanks a lot , It works perfectly using the left join :)